# TclTk standalone application Icon for Windows

Tags: icons, tcl, tk-toolkit, explorer

I want my standalone application written in TclTk to have a custom icon, not the default blue feather. I managed to accomplish this in OSX but I cannot do it in Windows. I have created an ico file from a png file. The problem is that when I create the startpack I receive the following error:

```
customizing tclkit.ico in executable
  icon 48x48/256: NOT SAME SIZE
  icon 32x32/256: NOT SAME SIZE
  icon 16x16/256: NOT SAME SIZE
  icon 0x0/256: NOT SAME SIZE
  icon 48x48/256: replaced
  icon 32x32/256: replaced
  icon 16x16/256: replaced
```

And indeed in several cases the icon shown in Windows Explorer is the blue feather and in some cases the icon is my custom icon.

I have prepared my ico file using ImageMagic like:

```
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  4 -colors  16 -resize  48x48  1.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  4 -colors  16 -resize  32x32  2.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  4 -colors  16 -resize  16x16  3.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  8 -colors 256 -resize  48x48  4.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  8 -colors 256 -resize  32x32  5.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth  8 -colors 256 -resize  16x16  6.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth 32 -colors 256 -resize 256x256 7.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth 32 -colors 256 -resize  48x48  8.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth 32 -colors 256 -resize  32x32  9.png
convert -background transparent p97-1o.png -depth 32 -colors 256 -resize  16x16 10.png

convert 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png tclkit.ico
rm 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png
```

Then I copy tclkit.ico to myapp.vfs/.

Then I create the start pack:

```
tclkit sdx.kit wrap myapp -runtime tclkit-8.6.3-win32-x86_64-2.exe
```

I have also tried several online converter but there are still several resolutions in the ico file that are not correctly change.

Any suggestions regarding how should I modify my ImageMagic conversion of the original png file so I get a proper icon file?

Comment: When you run imageMagick's 'identify' program on your icon file, what does it show?  I have only: `i/bdj_icon.ico[0] ICO 16x16 16x16+0+0 32-bit sRGB 30.7KB 0.000u 0:00.040
    i/bdj_icon.ico[1] ICO 32x32 32x32+0+0 32-bit sRGB 30.7KB 0.000u 0:00.040
    i/bdj_icon.ico[2] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 32-bit sRGB 30.7KB 0.000u 0:00.040
    i/bdj_icon.ico[3] PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 30.7KB 0.000u 0:00.000`

Comment: The output is like this:                                                                                          tclkit.ico[0] ICO 48x48 48x48+0+0 32-bit sRGB 367KB 0.000u 0:00.009
except for the 256x256:
tclkit.ico[6] PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 367KB 0.000u 0:00.009

Comment: What are the "several cases"?  In what situations are you seeing the feather?

Comment: After looking at your previous comment I realize the problem is with the 256x256 icon. So when I drag the file around I see the feather. Also when I press Shift Delete and received the warning I see the feather. Do you know why ImageMagic is not converting the png to icon in 256x256 size?

Comment: Can you try: [resource hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)  and see what icons are in the executable?   This tool has scripting capabilties so icon replacement could be automated.